# What does "minor key" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), Susan speaks to guitarist Steve:

> Susan: I'll go home and go to bed early, and you go to work.
>
> Steve: Okay. Just don't leave me in a **minor key**?

What does "minor key" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steve is a musician. In tonal music, a minor key is opposed to a major key, and in the grossest terms, minor may connote sadness or upset, while major is more associated with cheerfulness or joy.
(This simplification doesn't look at other modes, consideration of which isn't needed to explain this bit of English usage.)

[Merriam-Webster *minor key*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minor%20key)
1: a musical key or tonality in the minor mode
**2: a mood of melancholy or pathos**

[Collins *minor key*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/minor-key)
1. a key or mode based on a minor scale
**2. a less jubilant or more restrained mood, atmosphere, or quality**
"The conversation shifted to a minor key with news of the defeat"

Comment: +1 [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_(music)) might also be helpful.